# How to provide scope parameter to Bloc? Parametrized bloc or event with parameters?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Imagine a database where each table has a corresponding flutter BLOC.

Situation: my BLOC depends on some parameter XXX. Similar to a query `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id_category = XXX`

I could make my BLOC constructed with this parameter XXX like this.

```
BlocProvider<PupilBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) =>
                  PupilBloc(XXX)..add(LoadPupil()))
```

In my code different `PupilBloc` instances depend on the navigation (selection of the category XXX on the previous page). So, I think, there is no overlap between different `PupilBloc`'s.

I could as well put the parameter into the event.

```
BlocProvider<PupilBloc>(
              create: (BuildContext context) =>
                  PupilBloc()..add(LoadPupil(XXX)))
```

This event would load just the values with a matching XXX. Next time `LoadPupil()` event is emitted with a different parameter - it will reuse the same `PupilBloc` but will fetch new data which is corresponding to the parameter.

Those two approaches seem equivalent to me.
1. Multiple different parametrized BLOCs.
2. Single BLOC fetching different data based on the Event parameter.

Which way is better?

Answer (score 1):

If your Bloc has dependency on any same instances (like repository or class object) then approach A is the way to go, but if your Bloc doesn't have dependency like that and just need different value to fetch different data then you go with approach B. I am not really sure with your explanation about your case, but I think approach B is better.